# How to display xsl stylesheets in an offline environment?

Tags: java, jsp, xslt

I haven't worked with xsl sytlesheets in about 5 years.  I remember working with another developer to set up a way to display the xsl templates, without having to go through the flow in our application to actually display each page.  We would just create the xsl and then display it standalone offline from the app, but I don't recall how we did it.

It saved us a lot of time not having to actually navigate through the flow to get to the page and then see if it displayed properly.  Does anyone have a simple way to set this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean web-browsers?

```
<?xml-stylesheet href="example2.xsl" type="text/xsl" ?>
```

Read more http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT

Answer (score 1):

try using the XSLT transformer in popular XML editors;
www.oxygenxml.com is a good one

Comment: It's commercial, but expensive for what I need to do. I think it's $349 USD.  I found Alchemist XML Editor/IDE that will do XSLT debugging along with the editing, so I'm trying that.